# How to executeJavascript in selenium using javascript and return value

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using javascript for selenium `selenium-webdriver`.

My code is:

```
        var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
        this.driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)
            .build();

.
.
.

        driver.executeScript('return document.links;');
```

I dont know, how to return value from execute script.

`console.log(driver.executeScript('return document.links;'));` not working.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Take a look at the api docs: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html

Comment: Where is something about function `executeScript` ? Did you found something? If YES tell me where ;)

Comment: You're right. I could not find it there.

Comment: I found only this: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/ie_exports_Driver.html#executeScript but i still don't know how to use it.

Comment: And when you use the JavascriptExecutor. Like so:  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String Title =  js.executeScript('return document.title;').ToString();

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with `javascript` but in `java` we typecast returning object to String, As In javascript you can use `var` or `let` , I suggest to try this, no harm in it :-
`var url  = driver.executeScript('return document.links;');`

Comment: Simple return not working.

Comment: just check API documentation, it returns javascript promise

Comment: Sure, but how to read output from promise?

Comment: return the result via JSON.stringify?

Comment: ^^^ That returns.  Try that with console.log, but I suggest for your first example you use a variable to the left of executescript to catch the return as in `var someVar = driver.executeScript('return JSON.stringify(document.links)');`

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

public Object executeJavascript() {
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript('return document.links;');
}
```

Comment: It is not javascript.

Comment: for javascript you can use driver.executeScript('return document.links;').then(function(str) {console.log(str);});

Comment: [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L359) here are more example

Answer (score 0):

```
   const textPromise = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(xUserDataTF));
        textPromise.then((elem) => {
        driver.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', textPromise);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        logEverywhere('some error occured while finding userdata textfield');
      });
```

I am using it like this. Check out whether this works for you.